# Make many to many relation in Jetbrains exposed (Kotlin exposed)

Tags: java, sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

Just wondering if anyone has any examples or has ever done something similar, and could help me with this. My structure is as follows.
User has multiple roles
Roles have multiple Permissions, and the relevant users that match
Permissions have multiple roles and just a string, they need to be connected to the Roles via their ID. Just wondering how I can do this via jetbrains exposed, not looking for spoonfed code, just if anybody knows how I could do this through this library as I have never used it before.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO#many-to-many-reference

Comment: `Just wondering how I can do this via jetbrains exposed` - `via` is the key word here :D